# переменные в Ansible

Tags: ansible

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно из одного .yml файла брать значения полей, чтобы использовать в другом файле для конфигурирования ос?

Comment: Эммм... `include_vars`?

Answer (score 1):

В общем, разобрался:

```
tasks:
- name: Import any.yml
  include_vars:
    file: ./any.yml
    name: var

- name: Debug
  debug:
    msg: "{{ var.param.name }}"
```